# Eliminating free and unwanted points in a boundary plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, boundary

I have determined a boundary on a BW image

However i wish to get rid of the boundary that is generated on the edges of the image, as well as the free points,which are not part of the edge between the white and black parts.
How can it be done?

This is the code used to get the boundary

```
bw = imadjust(I1,[0 0.1],[0 1]);
BW= im2bw(bw);
%% plot boundary
[B,L,N] = bwboundaries(BW);
figure; imshow(BW); hold on; 
for k=1:length(B), 
   boundary = B{k};
   tempa = boundary(:,2); 
   tempb = boundary(:,1);
   if(k <=N) 
      plot(tempa,tempb,'r','LineWidth',1.5); 
   end
end
```

image with boundary

[image]

image without boundary

[image]

Comment: have you considered morphological cleaning as a pre-processing?

Answer (score 0):

For the boundary on the edge of your image, I think you should crop it properly first.

For the standalone points to not be detected, you should get rid of them, as Shai suggested.
Things you might be interested in are [imreconstruct](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imreconstruct.html) or [medfilt2](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html).

Maybe the [noise removal tutorial](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/noise-removal.html) might be interesting too.

Comment: I wish to use the array that stores the boundary as a vector graphic can you suggest how to eliminate those points which mark the edges from the array?
I have been trying to exclude these points. I am unable to put a finger on the right way to extract it from the cell arrays within the boundary array.